# django 'str' object has no attribute 'id' in getlist()

Tags: django, django-views

I have this function that I tried to use to perform a delete operation on some items

```
def return_buk(request):
    books = Books.objects.all()
    selected = request.POST.getlist('marked_delete')
    for book in books:
        for select in selected:
            if select.book_id_id == book.id:
                print(select.id)
```

However, when I try to access the attributes, I get an error like this.
Obviously the items in the `getlist` are coming as in `str` format. How can I get their attributes?

```
'str' object has no attribute 'id'
```

Model where marked_delete is coming from

```
class Issue(models.Model):
    borrower_id = models.ForeignKey(Student,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    book_id = models.ForeignKey(Books,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

Comment: What is marked_delete? is that ids of books?

Comment: They are IDs of items from another model. @Sumithran. Let me add the model where marked_delete is coming from.

Comment: add models too it is unclear qsn

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give this a try

```
selected_list = request.POST.getlist('marked_delete')
selected = Issue.objects.filter(id__in=selected_list)

for book in books:
    for select in selected:
        if select.book_id_id == book.id:
            print(select.id)
```

Comment: still, there is the question what is marked_delete, and what you want to do with the select.id? im asking this because of, you dont have to loop through every book objects present in the table, instead select the books that are present in the ```selected``` and do your thing whatever it is.. i think you got this